# How do I use Python to launch an interactive Docker container?

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, interactive

I am working with a Docker image which I launch in interactive mode like so: `docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash`

The actual image I work with has many complicated parameters, which is why I wrote a script to construct the full `docker run` command and launch it for me. As the logic grew more complicated, I want to migrate the script from bash to Python.

Using `docker-py`, I prepared everything to run the image. Seems like using `docker.containers.run` for interactive shells is [not supported](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/390), however. Using `subprocess` instead seems logical, so I tried the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '-it', '--rm', 'ubuntu', 'bash'])
```

But this gives me:

```
$ python3 docker_run_test.py 
$ unable to setup input stream: unable to set IO streams as raw terminal: input/output error
$
```

Note that the error message appears in a different shell prompt from the python command.

How do I make `python3 docker_run_test.py` to do equivalent of running `docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash`?

Comment: This is too complicated for subprocess to handle. Packer is the package for automating Docker tasks.

Comment: If your intent is to launch multiple docker containers and stop them in one shot, [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) might be what you are looking for. 
But if you wish to continue with python, you will probably need [pty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html)

Comment: Current answers are both adding an undersirable requirement of having docker cli installed, where docker-py can properly talk with remove hosts without requiring presence of docker-cli on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can we use this ?

```
import os
os.system('docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo-terminal to read from and write to the container process

```
import pty
import sys
import select
import os
import subprocess

pty, tty = pty.openpty()

p = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '-it', '--rm', 'ubuntu', 'bash'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)

while p.poll() is None:
    # Watch two files, STDIN of your Python process and the pseudo terminal
    r, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin, pty], [], [])
    if sys.stdin in r:
        input_from_your_terminal = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 10240)
        os.write(pty, input_from_your_terminal)
    elif pty in r:
        output_from_docker = os.read(pty, 10240)
        os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), output_from_docker)
```