# Centos 8 the input device is not a TTY Docker

Tags: python, docker, centos8

I am trying to run the following python code:

```
container = subprocess.Popen(["docker", "run","-ti", "--rm", "--name",imageName,imageName],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
c= container.communicate(input='some data'.encode())[0]
```

I tried this both on Windows and Centos 8 but I keep getting the error

```
the input device is not a TTY Docker
```

Comment: Try removing the "-ti". If you need an interactive session, you may want to look at the pty pseudo terminal library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59508881/1627968 for reference

Comment: Also have you added the `sh` command at the end?

Comment: I'd avoid using `subprocess` to launch containers; use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead.